# Change a view varible file with the html file

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments

I'm making an online store and I add to it the Stripe Checkout for payments, everything works correct, the problem is that the view function only manages one price. It looks like this:

```
def charge(request): # new
    if request.method == 'POST':
        charge = stripe.Charge.create(
            amount=179900,
            currency='mxn',
            description='Bota Caballero',
            source=request.POST['stripeToken']
        )
        return render(request, 'charge.html')
```

the amount says the price, In my html homepage I have a select tag, it defines the cost of the product

```
                           <select id="modelo" onchange="modelo()" class="select__option" required>
                                <option>Selecciona Modelo...</option>
                                <option>$1799</option>
                                <option>$1299</option>
                                <option>$1199</option>
                            </select>
```

I would like to change the amount variable of the view file depending on what is selected in the select tag. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would typically pass the value via your `form` and retrieve it with `request.POST.get('amount', None)` however..

You should **never** pass pricing from a client editable form.

As an example, if you `POST` a form with your selection to your `view` and then dynamically set that value to your amount, you set yourself up to some serious pricing issues.

The end user could simply modify the `POST` data and set whatever value they like.

---

I think the best solution here would be to:

1. Store the pricing you have set in your database
2. Pass the product identification or similar via `POST`
3. Retrieve pricing from database
4. Set dynamic pricing based on database response

Comment: Can u give a quick simple example with code? Im new to django and stripe. Thank you

Comment: @BernardoOlisan Simply write it like you would any other model. Assuming you have a model for managing products with the pricing stored within, retrieve the pricing from the model and use that to create your payment.

Comment: yes but the problem is that i dont have a model that can manage my products, my store is very simple, there are only 3 products so i didnt make a model for it

Comment: Make a model for it. Do not store this kind of stuff client side. Create a model, add products and pricing. Serve it in a form and then always validate data received from the user.

Comment: but i dont get how to do the dynamic price on the view, any example?

Comment: Use a form. Then when viewing a product the form can be passed in the page `GET` using `instance` to prepopulate fields with database objects. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/

Comment: okey, or maybe can I import the model of the product to the views.py and set the variable amount = the object of the model price?

Comment: Correct. You can do that. Whenever the user passes a product to the payment portal you should do a database check on the current price before creating it :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your select tag is within a form. You can simply retrieve the value/option selected by your user and use it in your view function to set the Stripe charge.

```
<select id="modelo" name="modelo_price" onchange="modelo()" class="select__option" required>
   <option>Selecciona Modelo...</option> 
   <option>$1799</option>
   <option>$1299</option>
   <option>$1199</option>
</select>
```

```
def charge(request): # new
   if request.method == 'POST':
      # Here you retrieve the value submitted by your user
      charge_amount = int(request.form.get('modelo_price')) * 100
      
      charge = stripe.Charge.create(
            amount=charge_amount,
            currency='mxn',
            description='Bota Caballero',
            source=request.POST['stripeToken']
        )
        return render(request, 'charge.html')
```

Comment: I have voted this down even though the answer would indeed solve the issue. Given the context that the user wants to create an online store, a user should never ever ever be aloud to define the pricing sent to `Stripe`. This solution allows an end user to modify the `POST` and set whatever value they deem suitable for the product. This is a massive security issue and should never make it to production.

Comment: @PacketLoss yes i will try yours for security

Comment: @PacketLoss is there a way to do it like this but with security?

Comment: @PacketLoss as the user mentioned, he is a beginners and this method is not only easy to implement but also easier to understand vs than calling a db connection.
It's super easy to implement security method to check that the value sent in the form has not been forged.